# Pass the cookie file into the curl request nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, http-headers, httprequest

I use cookies.txt extension of chrome to get cookies.txt after login to google.
The cookie file format is netscape cookie. Now I want pass this cookie file to http request by nodejs.

Command line I used:

```
curl -L -b cookie.txt https://myaccount.google.com/
```

But I couldn't find any documents that tell me about how to pass cookie file to curl function of nodejs.
How to convert the above command line to nodejs?

Update:
 cookie.txt format like this:

```
# HTTP Cookie File for mozilla.org by Genuinous @genuinous.
# To download cookies for this tab click here, or download all cookies.
# Usage Examples:
#   1) wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions"
#   2) curl --cookie cookies.txt "https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions"
#   3) aria2c --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions"
#
.mozilla.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1643553591  _ga GA1.2.176633766.1564724252
.developer.mozilla.org  TRUE    /   TRUE    1583073592  dwf_sg_task_completion  False
.mozilla.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1580567991  _gid    GA1.2.1169610322.1580463999
developer.mozilla.org   FALSE   /   FALSE   1580483392  lux_uid 158048125271715522
.mozilla.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1580481652  _gat    1
```

Nodejs code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.myaccount.google.com',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'whatever',
        'Referer': 'https://google.com/',
        'Cookie': ????
    }
};

http.get(options, callback);
```

Comment: In node.js, you need to set the [cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) with the request you're making.  If you show your nodejs code for making the request and show your cookie file, then people could help you more specifically.

Comment: I updated cookie.txt format.

Comment: The cookie header is like: `Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3` so that first cookie in your sample file would be `Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.176633766.1564724252;`

Comment: Is there a limit at which the `Cookie` header field is limited to, which may be much smaller than what's permissible in a cookie-jar file?

Answer (score 3):

There's the [npm cookiefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookiefile) package.  It can read the netscape-format cookiefile and generate the appropriate header.

It will send the cookies with all their expiration, path, and scope data from the cookiefile.

Something like this (not debugged):

```
var http = require('http');
const cookiefile = require('cookiefile')

const cookiemap = new cookiefile.CookieMap('path/to/cookie.txt')
const cookies = cookiemap.toRequestHeader().replace ('Cookie: ','')

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.myaccount.google.com',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'whatever',
        'Referer': 'https://google.com/',
        'Cookies': cookies
    }
};

http.get(options, callback);
```

Comment: I got error "Cookie File doesn't exists" after use your code.

Comment: Did you provide the cookie file's actual path in your call to the CookieMap constructor? Use your actual path in place of `path/to/cookie.txt`.

Comment: You're removing `Cookie:` and adding `Cookies` — just want to check if that was intentional? I'd never seen `Cookies` (plural) up until now.

Answer (score 1):

As it appears you already know, you just need to set the `Cookie` header based on the name and values that correspond to the target hostname.  Here's an example from your cookie file for the `developer.mozilla.org` domain:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    hostname: 'developer.mozilla.org',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'whatever',
        'Referer': 'https://google.com/',
        'Cookie': 'dwf_sg_task_completion=False; lux_uid=158048125271715522;'
    }
};

http.get(options, callback);
```